# HTML table to Android TableLayout

Tags: android, html, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have XML which I get from server and I have HTML table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">$kolumn1$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">$kolumn2$</td>
        <td>$kolumn3$</td>
        <td>$kolumn4$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$kolumn5$</td>
        <td colspan="3">$kolumn1$</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and now, I want to create Android TableLayout like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="3" />
</TableRow>
```

what is the best way to create TableLayout from HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 I have to like create Relative layout inside the TableRow
 And put the components to Relative layout
 It's worked me. I hope this will be worked for you also..
```